# Node js - How can I access to a SOAP WebService?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, express

This is the first time that I need to access to a Web Service.

I need to access to the Banxico SOAP Webservice to get the peso (M.N.) exchange rate to dollar. Im using Node with Express and Ive been reading the npm soap dependencie but Im getting confused with everything.
The info about Banxico Web Service is here:

http://www.anterior.banxico.org.mx/ley-de-transparencia/consultas-frecuentes/%7B960A6514-B048-02B8-4BF2-920034786674%7D.pdf

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

So you have a very generic question and I will answer it with my generic answer:

If you are using NodeJS to write a script/API/server whatever you are doing - I would strongly recommend to start reading documentation to this NPM module [SOAP for NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) I believe that library would have good documentation and examples.

Also read more on SOAP service in general and WSDLs. That would explain you what to do with this WSDL (http://www.banxico.org.mx/DgieWSWeb/DgieWS?WSDL) I took it from the website you provided in your question.

Finally I had a chance to write a REST API which was a wrapper around SOAP API back in a day [northern911-api](https://github.com/anvk/northern911-api) 
If you know what is REST API, REST, Express then I suggest you to take a look into it. It is relatively small code and might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by using below link
(https://github.com/milewise/node-soap)